# How to get params from response API Google via PHP

Tags: php, json, api, parameters, response

I use PHP call API from Google, but the API response is a function. someone know how can I get params "results" in response. Thanks

[image: G]

Comment: Can you show us what you tried please ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution is API response is jsonp, so I use:

```
function jsonp_decode($jsonp, $assoc = false) { // PHP 5.3 adds depth as third parameter to json_decode
    if($jsonp[0] !== '[' && $jsonp[0] !== '{') { // we have JSONP
       $jsonp = substr($jsonp, strpos($jsonp, '('));
    }
    return json_decode(trim($jsonp,'();'), $assoc);
}
```